# Is it possible to change the extension of a T4 template from .tt to something else?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, t4

I want to change the extension of a T4 template from .tt to something else.

Will it work?

Comment: Why do you want to use this? AFAIK atleast visual studio needs the extension to be `.tt` to execute it.

Comment: @gideon Pretty sure all you need to do is set the "custom tool" appropriately, and it works fine. I've seen this used in some NuGet packages, such as T4MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can suffix it whatever you like. As long as the CustomTool property is set to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` it will still work

Comment: +1 since you fleshed it out with the info on the CustomTool prop. One recommendation; change "suffix" to "extension"? (nitpick, I know!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Edit away if you like, but suffix is a verb and extension isn't :)

Comment: hehe... true; it would be more than a drop-xin edit. Nah, it's ok. I doubt anyone will be confused :)